# Xamarin Forms authentication - Authentication Providers?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

Newbie question here on Authentication.  I am used to incorporating authentication into my app backend server, like Spring Security Authentication for example.  I don't really understand how the authentication providers work.

My concern is that somehow each provider can only authenticate its own accounts, ie google can only authenticate for gmail accounts, and Azure Active directory can only authenticate some kind of Microsoft registered account?  I am disinclined to oauth because as a user I am always paranoid about signing in for some game or app from an unknown provider becacuse I never am sure whether I just gave my gmail or facebook account password to a rando.

I am fine giving people the option to use Oath, but less comfortable if that's the only option.  I would like people to be able to give me whatever email address they want, and a password which they create for my site only.

Also these questions:  If I use an authentication provider can I get the actual email address being used to log in?  Or do I only get a token?
  If I am going to build my own authentication service so I can accept any email domain as user name, what is the easiest to implement in Xamarin forms, and can somebody point me to a tutorial or something?

Advice appreciated thanks.

Comment: if you are implementing your own authentication you can use https services to connect to your server and your server can provide either token or whatever you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right, each identity provider provides the ability to authenticate their own users; Google OAuth supports Google accounts, Azure Active Directory supports Microsoft work & school accounts, Microsoft Account supports Microsoft personal accounts, and so on.

You have quite a few options on how to add support for these identity providers in your app, in addition to what we typically call 'local accounts', or accounts created specifically for the given application.  I'll list out a few approaches:

- You can write all the code yourself to integrate with each identity provider individually, and build-your-own local account solution as well.
- You can use an SDK/library in your Xamarin Forms which facilitates using multiple identity providers within your app.  The [`Xamarin.Auth`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/) package has historically served this purpose for Xamarin apps. It provides auth capabilities for Facebook, Google, Microsoft, and Twitter.
- You can use a dedicated cloud service which provides authentication services for your app.  Some examples include [Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users), [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), [Gigya](http://www.gigya.com/), and more. The exact identity providers supported and the level of support for Xamarin/Xamarin Forms will vary across each one.  [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) is another option that I know [supports Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) as well as Facebook, Google, Twitter, and local accounts (disclaimer: I work on AAD B2C). These services sometimes have free tiers & paid tiers, so  you can compare & contrast each.
- You could also build your own authentication service using open source code like [Identity Server](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) if you wish.

It definitely depends which route you go, but generally speaking each solution will provide you access to some user profile information upon user authentication.  For Azure AD B2C, you can configure the claims that are returned to your application in the tokens your app receives.  For other services, you may need to make a REST API call to get some user data like the email address.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks very helpful  If I use Azure AD B2C, will that permit my users to use any email address they wish and any password they wish? Or is it restricted to using only the supported Authentication Providers?